# Can't get socket.io to function properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

(Heads up I literally started programming like 1 week ago)

So I'm trying to use node.js and socket.io to make a simple multiplayer snake game. I also wanted to use my custom domain (https://trononline.tech (it has a snake game, but not the one I want)), but I cant do that without this console error: https://ibb.co/RhpHK5H

It's really annoying and no matter what I try it doesn't seem to change.

My code:

```js
//server.js
const io = require('socket.io')();
const { initGame, gameLoop, getUpdatedVelocity} = require('./game');
const { FRAME_RATE } = require('./constants');
const{ makeid } = require('./utils')

const state = {};
const clientRooms = {};

io.on('connection', client => {
    const state = initGame;

    client.on('keydown', handleKeydown);
    client.on('newGame', handleNewGame);
    client.on('joinGame', handleJoinGame);

    function handleJoinGame(gameCode) {
        const room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[gameCode];

        let allUsers;
         if (room) {
             allUsers = room.sockets;
         }
         let numClients = 0;
         if (allUsers) {
             numClients = Object.keys(allUsers).length;
         }
         if (numClients === 0) {
             client.emit('unknownGame');
             return;
         } else if (numClients > 1) {
             client.emit('tooManyPlayers');
             return;
         }
         clientRooms[client.id] = gameCode;

         client.join(gameCode);
         client.number = 2;
         client.emit('init', 2);

         startGameInterval(gameCode);
    }

    function handleNewGame() {
        let roomName = makeid(5);
        clientRooms[client.id] = roomName;
        client.emit('gameCode', roomName);

        state[roomName] = initGame();

        client.join(roomName)
        client.number = 1;
        client.emit('init', 1);
    }

    function handleKeydown(keyCode) {
        const roomName = clientRooms[client.id];

        if (!roomName) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            keyCode = parseInt(keyCode);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(e);
            return;
        }
        const vel = getUpdatedVelocity(keyCode);
            if (vel) {
                state[roomName].players[client.number - 1].vel = vel;
            }
    }

    startGameInterval(client, state);
});

function startGameInterval (roomName) {
   const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const winner = gameLoop(state[roomName]);

      if(!winner) {
         emitGameState('roomName', state[roomName]);
      } else {
         emitGameOver(roomName, winner);
         state[roomName] = null;
         clearInterval(intervalId);
      }

   }, 1000 / FRAME_RATE);
}
function emitGameState(roomName, state) {
    io.sockets.in(roomName)
        .emit('gameState', JSON.stringify(state));
}

function emitGameOver(roomName, winner) {
    io.sockets.in(roomName)
        .emit('gameOver', JSON.stringify({ winner }))
}

//index.js

const FOOD_COLOUR = '#FF0000';

const socket = io("https://trononline.tech/snake");


socket.on('init', handleInit);
socket.on('gameState', handleGameState);
socket.on('gameOver', handleGameOver);
socket.on ('gameCode', handleGameCode);
socket.on('unknownGame', handleUnknownGame);
socket.on('tooManyPlayers', handleTooManyPlayers);

const gameScreen = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
const initialScreen = document.getElementById('initialScreen');
const newGameButton = document.getElementById('newGameButton');
const joinGameButton = document.getElementById('joinGameButton');
const gameCodeInput = document.getElementById('gameCodeInput');
const gameCodeDisplay = document.getElementById('gameCodeDisplay')

newGameButton.addEventListener('click', newGame);
joinGameButton.addEventListener('click', joinGame);


function newGame() {
    socket.emit('newGame');
    init();
}

function joinGame() {
    const code = gameCodeInput.value;
    socket.emit('joinGame', code);
    init();

}

let canvas, ctx;
let playerNumber
let gameActive = false;

function init() {
    initialScreen.style.display = "none";
    gameScreen.style.display = "block";

    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;

    ctx.fillStyle = BG_COLOUR;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', keydown);
    gameActive = true;
}
function keydown (e) {
    socket.emit('keydown', e.keyCode);
}
function paintGame(state) {
    ctx.fillStyle = BG_COLOUR;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    const food = state.food;
    const gridSize = state.gridSize;
    const size = canvas.width / gridSize;

    ctx.fillStyle = FOOD_COLOUR;
    ctx.fillRect(food.x * size, food.y * size, size, size);

    paintPlayer(state.players[0], size, SNAKE1_COLOUR);
    paintPlayer(state.players[1], size, SNAKE2_COLOUR);
}

    function paintPlayer(playerState, size, colour) {

        const snake = playerState.snake;

        ctx.fillStyle = colour;
        for (let cell of snake) {
            ctx.fillRect(cell.x * size, cell.y * size, size, size);
        }
    }
function handleInit (number) {
    playerNumber = number;
}

function handleGameState(gameState) {
    if (!gameActive) {
        return;
    }
    gameState = JSON.parse(gameState);
    requestAnimationFrame(() => paintGame(gameState));
}
function handleGameOver(data) {
    if (!gameActive) {
        return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    if (data.winner === playerNumber) {
        alert("You win! :^)");
    } else {
        alert("You lose. :^(")
    }
    gameActive = false;
}
function handleGameCode(gameCode) {
    gameCodeDisplay.textContent = gameCode;
}
function handleUnknownGame() {
    reset();
    alert("Unknown game code")
}

function handleTooManyPlayers() {
reset();
alert("This game is already in progress");
}
function reset() {
    playerNumber = null;
    gameCodeInput.value = "";
    initialScreen.style.display = "block";
    gameScreen.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MultiPlayer Snake</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        #gameScreen {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section class="vh-100">
    <div class="container h-100">

        <div id="initialScreen" class="h-100">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
                <h1>Multiplayer Snake</h1>
                <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-success"
                        id="newGameButton"
                >
                    Create New Game
                </button>
                <div>OR</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gameCodeInput"></label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Game Code" id="gameCodeInput"/>
                </div>
                <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="btn btn-success"
                        id="joinGameButton"
                >
                    Join Game
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="gameScreen" class="h-100">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">

                <h1>Your game code is: <span id="gameCodeDisplay"></span></h1>

                <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

To be honest I don't know what I've tried yet because they were mostly just minor tweaks that resulted in nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are making HTTP requests to your domain name `trononline.tech` from `localhost`. Since these names do not match, this counts as a cross-origin HTTP request. By default, this is not permitted to protect your website but you can enable it manually. See this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) about CORS headers and this [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

See this answer from [apsiller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/10161292) for more information.

Comment: For the NPM module, where do I use it? On my custom domain, or in a file in the code of the game? And which file would I do it in?

Comment: You should use the module in your backend server for the game. If you are not already using it, I suggest looking into [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/).